# Find $a$ and $b$ if $\lim _{x\to 3}\frac{3x^2+ax+b}{x^2-2x-3} = \frac{5}{2}$ exists

Tags: algebra-precalculus, limits

How to find $a$ and $b$ of this expression or limit $$\lim _{x\to 3}\frac{3x^2+ax+b}{x^2-2x-3}=\frac{5}{2}$$

I don't really have any clue on how to solve this

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9201), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: What previously worked examples, theorems, or solved problems in your math education, that you feel might be pertinent, led up to this problem?

Comment: @Ceerwin Yamson : Hi, Welcome to MSE, please show your effort in the question body to avoid downvote and closing. I think you ask a nice question.

Comment: Hint: Both the numerator and denominator are continuous functions.  As $~x \to 3,~$ the denominator goes to $~0.~$  So, as $~x \to 3,~$ what can you surmise must happen to the numerator, in order to satisfy the constraint that the fraction goes to $~(5/2)~?$

Answer (score 2):

The first point you should think about is ... when the limit is a number (not $\infty$)  so must be a $(x-3)$ in numerator. so $$\lim _{x\to 3}\frac{3x^2+ax+b}{x^2-2x-3}=\frac{5}{2}\\\lim _{x\to 3}\frac{3x^2+ax+b}{(x-3)(x+1)}=\frac{5}{2}\\\lim _{x\to 3}\frac{(x-3)(something)}{(x-3)(x+1)}=\frac{5}{2}
$$
now you can divide $3x^2+ax+b$ by $(x-3)$ and residual must be zero.
then by simplification of $(x-3)$ you have $\frac{(3x+...)}{x+1}|_{x=3} \ =\frac 52$  can you take over now?

Comment: @user2661923: Yes, thank you for notifying me, I fix it as soon as possible.